# Issue accessing enums with the same name, different parents

Tags: javascript, node.js, enums

I need to access both the enum values(2 and 20) related to `SuperUser`

---

**enums.js**

```
var RoleType = {
    User: 1,
    SuperUser: 2
};

var ActionType = {
    User: 10,
    SuperUser: 20
};

module.exports= RoleType , ActionType;
```

**roleController.js**

```
const enums = require('../common/enums');
console.log(enums)
const roleType = enums.RoleType.SuperUser;
const actionType = enums.ActionType.SuperUser;
```

Once I print the enums, it only shows the `RoleType` section as below.

```
{ User: 1, SuperUser: 2}
```

I tried the below codes. Added the result I got as comments.

```
const roleType = enums.SuperUser;    // Prints 2
const actionType = enums.SuperUser;  // Prints 2
const roleType = enums.RoleType.SuperUser;    // RoleType undefined
const actionType = enums.ActionType.SuperUser;  // ActionType undefined
```

How can I access these values separately?

Comment: `module.exports = { RoleType , ActionType };`

Comment: @epascarello It worked. Could you please add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello)

```
module.exports = { RoleType , ActionType };
```